# Adding EditText with button click

Tags: javascript, android, android-activity, android-studio, android-edittext

EBelow is my code for adding EditText to my layout and it works fine but I want it to create the new EditText boxes below the ones that was created. If you see something in the code I should change or improve, pls comment.Thanks in advance.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_weight_log);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    tt= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tt);
    dd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dd);
    aa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    aa.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {public void onClick
                (View  v) { aa();}});

}


public void aa()
{         for(i = 0; i <100; ++i);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)  findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);
    params.setMargins(0,600,0,0);

        EditText edtTxt = new EditText(this);
        int maxLength = 5;
        edtTxt.setHint("editText1");
        edtTxt.setLayoutParams(params);
        edtTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        edtTxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME);
        edtTxt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,18);
        InputFilter[] fArray = new InputFilter[1];
        fArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
        edtTxt.setFilters(fArray);


    layout.addView(edtTxt);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            params1.setMargins(0,600,0,0);

    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    int maxLength1 = 4;
    editText.setHint("editText2");
    editText.setLayoutParams(params1);
    editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    editText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,18);
    fArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength1);
    editText.setFilters(fArray);

    layout.addView(editText);


    }
```

Comment: Check out 'aa' in the onCreate method

Comment: That was a mistake I made when I copied over the code, I made the corrections now. Im still having problems getting new EditTexts below the ones created.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to linear layout and setting its orientation to vertical. Then if you will add a new view it will be added below your previous view.

Comment: I tried this but I want the EditTexts to be accross from wach other. I don't know how to do that in Linear Layout.

Comment: Actually, I figured out how to do it with your ans and Sachin's example. Thanks for the help!